# ffmpeg2 on ubuntu 12.10 quantal server

Tags: 12.10, server, ffmpeg

currently i'm stuck with installing ffmpeg2 via the repository ppa:samrog131/ppa.

Why it doesn't work? On various sites it's been said, that the ppa is for ubuntu 12.10.
Am i doing something wrong? Because it is installing ffmpeg from standard ubuntu repository ( 0.8.6)

Hope anybody could help :/

Comment: What is the output of `apt-cache policy ffmpeg`? Which command have you used to install that package? Did you run `sudo apt-get update` between adding the PPA and package installation?

Comment: Hey, i did! I already upgraded to 12.10 :/ 

ffmpeg:
  Installed: 6:0.8.6-0ubuntu0.12.10.1
  Candidate: 6:0.8.6-0ubuntu0.12.10.1
  Version table:
 *** 6:0.8.6-0ubuntu0.12.10.1 0
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     6:0.8.3-6ubuntu2 0
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal/main amd64 Packages

Comment: And how have you installed it? It seems the package name in that PPA is `ffmpeg-real`...

Comment: I think it's something different. A server or sth. Nothing changed :/

Answer (score 0):

**ffmpeg-real**

```
apt-cache show ffmpeg-real
```

> Description: multimedia player, server and encoder
>
> FFmpeg is a
>   complete, cross-platform solution to record, convert and stream audio
>   and video.
>
> This is the real ffmpeg. The binaries are installed to the
>   /opt/ffmpeg/bin. The man pages are  installed to the
>   /opt/ffmpeg/share/man.

The ffmpeg is installed to the /opt. It is not replacing the official Ubuntu version of the ffmpeg. The ffmpeg version 2 will start with the command:

```
/opt/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg
```

The ffmpeg can started with the command: 'ffmpeg' with the Debian alternatives - another package:

**ffmpeg-set-alternatives**

```
apt-cache show ffmpeg-set-alternatives
```

> Description: a package to create the Debian alternatives for the
>   ffmpeg.
>
> A helper package to create and remove the alternatives for
>   the ffmpeg.
>
> The Debian alternatives system (man
>   update-alternatives):
>
> It is possible for several programs
>   fulfilling the same or similar functions  to be installed on a single
>   system  at the  same  time. For example,  many systems have several
>   text editors installed at once. This gives choice to the  users of a
>   system, allowing each to use a different editor, if desired,  but
>   makes it difficult  for  a  program  to make a good choice for an
>   editor  to invoke if the user has not specified a particular
>   preference.  Debian's  alternatives  system aims to solve this
>   problem.
>
> This package creates alternatives for the ffmpeg, ffplay,
>   ffprobe and the ffserver.
>
> The alternatives are removed when this
>   package is removed.
>
> Configuring of the alternatives can be made by
>   the command line (man update-alternatives)  or with the kalternatives.

**An Example**

Start situation: Package ffmpeg is installed from the official Ubuntu repositories.

```
:~$ ffmpeg
ffmpeg version 0.8.6-6:0.8.6-0ubuntu0.12.10.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the Libav developers
  built on Apr  2 2013 17:02:16 with gcc 4.7.2
*** THIS PROGRAM IS DEPRECATED ***
This program is only provided for compatibility and will be removed in a future release. Please use avconv instead.
Hyper fast Audio and Video encoder
usage: ffmpeg [options] [[infile options] -i infile]... {[outfile options] outfile}...

Use -h to get full help or, even better, run 'man ffmpeg'
```

The ffmpeg-set-alternatives is recommending the kalternatives.

The kalternatives is:

```
apt-cache show kalternatives

Description: graphical alternatives system configuration tool
Kalternatives offers a GUI to configure the alternative systems (a
system that allows you to select one alternative file for many in the
filesystem).
Kalternatives is available as KDE configuration module, integrated by default
into KDE's System Settings.
.
This is an advanced GUI of the update-alternatives program shipped with dpkg.
```

There is also the galternatives:

```
apt-cache show galternatives

Description: graphical setup tool for the alternatives system
A GUI to help the system administrator to choose what program
should provide a given service.
 .
This is a graphical front-end to the update-alternatives
program shipped with dpkg.
```

Installing the ffmpeg-set-alternatives with the option --no-install-recommends

```
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg-set-alternatives --no-install-recommends

The following NEW packages will be installed:
ffmpeg-real ffmpeg-set-alternatives libavcodec55-ffmpeg libavdevice55-ffmpeg
libavfilter3-ffmpeg libavformat55-ffmpeg libavutil52-ffmpeg
libpostproc52-ffmpeg libswresample0-ffmpeg libswscale2-ffmpeg
0 upgraded, 10 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 6,105 kB of archives.
After this operation, 16.2 MB of additional disk space will be used.
...
Setting up ffmpeg-set-alternatives (0.1~quantal~ppa1) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/ffmpeg to provide /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg (ffmpeg) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/ffplay to provide /usr/local/bin/ffplay (ffplay) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/ffprobe to provide /usr/local/bin/ffprobe (ffprobe) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/ffserver to provide /usr/local/bin/ffserver (ffserver) in auto mode
Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
```

Now there are options (list):

```
update-alternatives --list ffmpeg
/opt/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg
/usr/bin/ffmpeg
```

Picking the wanted ffmpeg (config)

```
sudo update-alternatives --config ffmpeg


There are 2 choices for the alternative ffmpeg (providing /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg).

  Selection    Path                    Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/bin/ffmpeg          20        auto mode
  1            /opt/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg   10        manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/ffmpeg          20        manual mode

Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 1
update-alternatives: using /opt/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg to provide /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg (ffmpeg) in manual mode
```

...and the ffmpeg command is telling (at here):

```
:~$ ffmpeg
ffmpeg version 2.0.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Oct  9 2013 20:12:01 with gcc 4.7 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.2-2ubuntu1)
  configuration: --prefix=/opt/ffmpeg --libdir=/opt/ffmpeg/lib/ --enable-shared --disable-stripping --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-postproc --enable-x11grab --enable-libcdio --enable-vaapi --enable-vdpau --enable-bzlib --enable-gnutls --enable-libgsm --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libfaac --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-nonfree --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libfdk_aac --enable-libopus --enable-pthreads --enable-zlib --enable-libvpx --enable-libfreetype --enable-libpulse
  libavutil      52. 38.100 / 52. 38.100
  libavcodec     55. 18.102 / 55. 18.102
  libavformat    55. 12.100 / 55. 12.100
  libavdevice    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
  libavfilter     3. 79.101 /  3. 79.101
  libswscale      2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100
  libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
Hyper fast Audio and Video encoder
usage: ffmpeg [options] [[infile options] -i infile]... {[outfile options] outfile}...

Use -h to get full help or, even better, run 'man ffmpeg'
```